# extract signature from digital certificate

Tags: python, pdf, openssl, digital-signature, pyopenssl

I get lot of pdfs in my system. I need to check if all of these files are:-

- digitally signed
- their integrity maintained(by comparing the hash of file content with the message digest embedded in /Contents.[image: signature dictionary].

I am using python to do this. Till now I have been able to get the `/Content` from signature dictionary using PyPDF2. The content is pkcs7--der encoded. Is there a way I can extract the signed message digest?

Similar operation was done in `C` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224757/how-can-i-extract-signature-from-pkcs7-envelop)

Comment: How did you get the value of '/Content' node from pdf using PyPDF2?

Answer (score 1):

DER is binary format, its structure is called ASN.1. PEM format is Base64 encoded DER.

This online PEM decoder is very useful: http://lapo.it/asn1js/ After you identify the message signature in it, you can write code to extract it by any ASN.1 library.

Comment: Wel thanks for the direction. I have the decoded DER from the link you provided. 1) How do identify the signature? 2) Would the ASN.1 library let me parse this file and get what I desire? Have not worked much on all of it. I am still checking if all that helps. Will update once I am done. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd look into the corresponding [RFC2315](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315) for correct signature structure. The ASN.1 library will expect only the DER/PEM encoded data, you need to extract it out of your PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The [SignedData](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5126#section-5.4) subtype of a [CADES](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5126), [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852) or [PKCS#7 1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) signature has a collection of [SignerInfo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5126#section-5.6) blocks [defined here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852#section-5.3) contains basically:

- SignerIdentifier: key into certificates collection
- DigestAlgorithmIdentifier: which algorithm was used to calculate message digest
- SignedAttributes (optional): the sealed data:
- SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier: which algorithm was used to calculate the signature (over SignedAttributes)
- SignatureValue: the signature value
- UnsignedAttributes (optional)

The SignedAttributes may contain, depending on the type of signature:

- ContentType: type of signed content
- MessageDigest
- SigningTime
- CounterSignature

If we would simplify this using just the first signature found and using [my fork](https://github.com/erny/pyx509) of [pyx509](https://github.com/hiviah/pyx509) this could be some type of code like this one (not tested):

```
from pyx509.models import PKCS7
pkcs7 = PKCS7.from_der(here_goes_your_pks7_signature_data_der_encoded)
signer_info = pkcs7.content.signerInfos[0]
auth_attrs = signer_info.auth_attributes
for attr in auth_attrs.attributes:
    if attr.type == '1.2.840.113549.1.9.4':  # Message Digest OID
        message_digest = attr.value
        print "Digest: %s#%s" % (signer_info.oid2name(signer_info.digest_algorithm), messageDigest)
```

Comment: *If we would simplify this using just the first signature found* - integrated PDF signatures allow only a single `SignerInfo` in each `SignedData`; so, no simplification warning required in this respect.